# SSH connected remote server is using my local computer's internet

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, sshd

I'm new to Ubuntu. And im not quite sure about this. Im connected to my remote server hosted by Digital Ocean with `SSH`. My local internet speed is around 120 kbps. When I download something on the server through `wget` it downloads with a speed of 120kbps. Whereas when I ran a quick internet speed test, the results are:

```
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 690.98 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 297.49 Mbit/s
```

Also when I create a torrent through the server, the upload speed too is quite less. It's similar to my local pc's upload speed. I really dont know what the problem is. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

turns out the "wget" download was working again with the server's internet download speed @ 74mbps. But I still get 100kbps upload speed for torrents. What im trying to do is download large files on the server, create torrents of them, and download these torrents on my local computer. But the server's upload speed is too low. Similar to my local machine's upload speed. Im using Transmission, i've also tried this with deluge. I useits gui application through ssh with the option `-X` .

Comment: Could you record a terminal session as you log in to DO and then download. Without knowing what commands you're putting in to which sessions, and being able to confirm on screen that you're entering them in the remote and not local session, etc., it's hard to give advice. `script my-session` will record all the input/output in your console and save it as "my-session" (check you haven't got any login credentials in that file before upload).
Just for avoidance of doubt, all downloads to your local computer will be throttled to your local internet speed of 120kbps.

Comment: @pbhj , I've updated the question. Please take a look at it again!

Comment: Without any information about the network on your server and any rate limiting that may be in effect, it's not possible for us to explain in any great detail . To put it bluntly, when you are logged in via SSH you are using the servers resources in that terminal session.  X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
             ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
             user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display
             through the forwarded connection.  An attacker could gain access. See `man ssh`

Answer (score 0):

Your server's upload speed to an imaginary ultra-fast server is 300 Mbit/s

Your local connection's download speed from an imaginary ultra-fast server is 120kbps (>2000 times slower).

The 120kbps is the limiting factor when you download from your server to your local PC. Your server may be capable of pushing 300 Mbit/s to another fast server but this doesn't mean that it will be able to do the same through the slower connection to your local PC.

Comment: so what do I do here? I've a very large file on the server which I want to transfer to my local computer? Please help!

Comment: Sorry, you are a bit out of luck. If the server is not far you could try getting there with a portable hard drive. Or you could ask friends with faster connection (i.e. fatter pipes) to download it for you and copy it to a portable hard drive.